# Flutter FutureBuilder Logic

Tags: asynchronous, flutter

Looking around on the web, people have said that I shouldn't put any logic within build() of my stateful widget. Instead, they suggest that I should put my logic within initState(). (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11426)

However, if I am using a FutureBuilder in build(), to return different views (a progress indicator and the actual page), how do I put the logic dealing with the data from the FutureBuilder outside of build()?

Answer (score 0):

It's ok to have *UI logic* in your build method. You can totally deal with the `FutureBuilder` data inside the builder body. That's actually where you should do it.

The recommendation in that issue was against e.g. triggering a network call inside build.

Comment: :) thanks for the answer. The same issue was happening to me, I just didn't articulate it clearly. But I ended up fixing it.

Comment: How did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

To give a little more insight, within my FutureBuilder, I had a button that led me to an "edit" page. The edit page had a bunch of different views attached to it, and whenever I came back to the edit page to 'submit' my edit, FutureBuilder would fire and cause the edits I made to vanish.

I solved this by decoupling the UI and data within my FutureBuilder, so that FutureBuilder wouldn't keep building in the background and causing my edit page to update unexpectedly. My solution feels a little convoluted but after hours of hair pulling, I'm satisfied that it just works ;)

Comment: Update: understanding flutter's stateful and stateless lifecycles has helped me a lot to avoid problems such as this. Also, keeping in mind that flutter calls build essentially every second helped me to find workarounds when I had issues.